# Is there a way to find all consecutive subsets of a group in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a `tsibble` containing daily observations of multiple attributes. I have grouped these observations by an attribute and would like to generate all possible consecutive subsets of a given size `n` within the grouped data.
For instance, say I have the dataframe:

```
County,  State, fips_code, date,       workplace_trend
Autauga, AL,    1001,      2020-07-07, -30
Autauga, AL,    1001,      2020-07-08, -29
Autauga, AL,    1001,      2020-07-09, -29
Baldwin, AL,    1003,      2020-04-02, -35
Baldwin, AL,    1003,      2020-04-03, -36
Baldwin, AL,    1003,      2020-04-04, -27
```

and that I grouped my data by `fips_code`, and that I want to further group by all consecutive subsets of each group of size `n=2`. In the case of Autauga county, generating all possible consecutive sequences of size `n=2` would generate the following groups:

```
County,  State, fips_code, date,       workplace_trend
Autauga, AL,    1001,      2020-07-07, -30
Autauga, AL,    1001,      2020-07-08, -29
```

```
County,  State, fips_code, date,       workplace_trend
Autauga, AL,    1001,      2020-07-08, -29
Autauga, AL,    1001,      2020-07-09, -29
```

How can this be done in R?

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

n <- 2
result <- df %>%
           group_split(fips_code) %>%
           map(~combn(1:nrow(.x), n, function(x) .x[x, ], simplify = FALSE))
```

Since we have daily data to get consecutive rows we can do :

```
df %>%
  arrange(County, date) %>%
  group_split(fips_code) %>%
  map(function(x) {
    map(1:(nrow(x) - n + 1), ~x %>% slice(.x:(.x + n - 1)))
  }) -> result
```

Comment: This is great! Is there any way to do the same thing while preserving order? The goal is to only generate sequences containing consecutive days.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean by preserving order? Can you show example output that you are looking for based on the data that you have shared.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear. Dates should only be consecutive days.

Comment: @GunnarSundberg I'd suggest you use the word "consecutive" in your question. For the set {1,2,3}, "ordered" implies that {1,3} is valid but {3,1} is not. *Consecutive* is how you get {1,2} and {2,3} but not {1,3}.

Comment: @GunnarSundberg Check updated answer to get consecutive days.